# How to use custom HTTP methods in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I can't find way to perform some types of requests (like `REPORT` and `PROPFIND`, that used in webDav protocol). In general, how can I send a request with an arbitrary method name?

Answer (score 5):

Go to menu **Requests** > **Set Custom HTTP Method** (or press **⌥⌘M**) and enter whichever method you need.

[image: Set a custom HTTP method in Paw]